# DocumentFilter: Why is replace() invoked and not insertString()?

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent, documentfilter

I've implemented a `DocumentFilter` subclass, and when I type text into the `JTextComponent`, the `replace()` method of the filter is invoked, and not `insertString()` (which is never invoked). Any idea why that is?

Comment: What do you mean "why that is"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `insertString(...)` method is invoked when you update the Document directly, by using the Document.insertString(...) method.

The `replace(...)` method is invoked when the Document is updated by methods of the View (ie. the JTextField) when the user enters text or the user invokes Actions (cut, paste) associated with the text field.

I guess its is easier to always do a replace and then let the replace logic check to see if remove/insert is required.